# How to get the name of an element in PubChemPy?

Tags: python, pubchem

Can you please tell me if it is possible to get the name of an element in PubChemPy?
I found in the documentation that can find the PubChem CID by name:

```
result = pcp.get_compounds('Glucose', 'name')
print(result)

[Compound(5793)]
```

But I need the other way around, by CID to find the name of the element. Maybe someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Compound with CID as follows:

```
c = pcp.Compound.from_cid(5090)
```

then you can get all the information you need from this object.
for example:

```
>>> print c.iupac_name
3-(4-methylsulfonylphenyl)-4-phenyl-2H-furan-5-one
```

Check the [docs](https://pubchempy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/gettingstarted.html) for more info on the object attrs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly what I wanted to get. I need to get the title like in **[here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)**. That is, cid=5090 is "Rofecoxib", as **[here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/5090)**. Probably with the help of PubChemPy I will not be able to get what I want.

Comment: @Kate, the iupac is the real name like the one you want, sometimes when the molecule does not have the name yet, you would get a checmical name like: (6-hexadecanoyloxy-3,4,5-trihydroxy-1-oxohexan-2-yl)-methylazanide (for instance for this molecule: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/22079489) but if a molecule has a proper name assigned to it, you will get that proper name while calling the 'iupac' on the compound.